# Change first page of my jsp web project

Tags: jsp, web.xml

I'm trying to change the first page that shows when I acess my project:

```
localhost/MyProjct/
```

It returns the `index.jsp` page, but i need `login.jsp`. I tried this on my web.xml:

```
<web-app>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

It keeps sending me to `index.jsp`. Does anyone know what I'm doing wring?

Comment: Try clean and build . some changes in web.xml are not updated on auto deploy

Comment: Already did. It wont change :(

Comment: Do you have security configured in your app?

Comment: Are you sure you have only one entry in welcome-file-list as `<welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>` and the file named `login.jsp` under webpages ?

Comment: Clear the browser cache and temporary rename index.jsp, just to see if it is hitting your app.

Comment: @PredragMaric not yet.

Comment: @SanKrish yes, i do.

Comment: @AndreDuarte Are you checking for any session in your app . i advise you try Gas suggestion

Comment: Just did. Renamed my `index.jsp` and empty all cache from my browser and it returns me `404 error`.

Comment: Are you, by any chance, redirecting the request on the server side?

Comment: @PredragMaric on my login.jsp?

Comment: If you enter login.jsp manually, what page does it open?

Comment: The right login.jsp page. I did not solved my problem yet, so if you guys have anything else, please help.